# Writing into a specific location in a text file

Tags: python, text, overwrite, file-writing

How do I add a string/integer into an existing text file at a specific location?
My sample text looks like below:

```txt
No, Color, Height, age
1, blue,70,
2, white,65,
3, brown,49,
4, purple,71,
5, grey,60,
```

My text file has 4 columns, three columns have text, how do I write to any row in the fourth column?
If I want to write 12 to the second row, the updated file (sample.txt) should look like this:

```txt
No, Color, Height, age
1, blue,70,12
2, white,65,
3, brown,49,
4, purple,71,
5, grey,60,
```

I have tried this:

```py
with open("sample.txt",'r') as file:
    data =file.readlines()
data[1]. split(",") [3] = 1
with open ('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.writelines(data)
with open ('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    print (file. Read())
```

But it does not work. Your help is needed.

Comment: You've edited the row after splitting it, but have not done anything to mutate the original row. Try `data[1] = split_data_1.join(',')` or similar after performing the split and mutate.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is read that text file to a list & append based on index as follows.

```
with open('sample.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

line1 = lines[1]
new_line1 = line1 + str(12)
lines[1] = new_line1

with open('sample.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

### Updated sample.txt

```
No, Color, Height, age
1, blue,70,12
2, white,65,
3, brown,49,
4, purple,71,
5, grey,60,
```

### Explination:

Once you read the text file to list.

```
0th element will ebcome  ---> index(1st line)
1st element will become ----> 2nd line 
---
--

--
```

Access based on index & append your strings uinsg `+` operator

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works, but if I run it twice it appends towards the right of the previous content, initially12 was inputted, if I run it again, it becomes 1212. Is it possible to improve the code so that it always maintain the same content even if it is run more than once?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I used a 2D array and it worked for me. Try it out and send a chat to me if it doesn't work or if you need a more in-depth explanation.

```py
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as file:
  data = file.readlines()

  for index, item in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = item.strip("\n")

  for index, item in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = item.split(", ")

data[1][3] = "12"

ndata = []

for index, _ in enumerate(data):
  data1 = ", ".join(data[index])
  ndata.append(data1)

mdata = "\n".join(ndata)

with open("sample.txt", 'w') as file:
  file.write(mdata)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, but I got this error running it. 
data[1][3] = "12"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range